# Wacom tablet only works when USB mouse also attached

Tags: upgrade, 15.10, tablet, wacom

I use a Wacom Intuos 2 tablet.  After upgrading from Vivid to Wily it won't work unless I also have a regular USB mouse plugged in.  I've tried completely removing and reinstalling xserver-xorg-wacom, but unlike for 
previous upgrades, this doesn't fix things. I checked that the wacom module is loaded.

rquint@Maria-Agnesi:~$ lsmod | grep "wacom"

wacom                  81920  0

hid                   118784  3 wacom,hid_generic,usbhid

Comment: I decided to try doing a fresh install of Wily to see if the tablet would work.  Now I have a different situation.  After a fresh install I plugged in the tablet and it did not work.  Running xsetwacom showed it was recognized.

Comment: I've posted a new question which is more precise in identifying when and what the problem is.